# Undefined references when cross-compiling code to run on x86_64-linux-android: gethostid, assert_fail, errno_location not found

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am building some code that is mainly FORTRAN (eek) but also has some C code.  I am using NDK revision 21 (android-ndk-r21d).  All is well, until the main program link, when I get undefined references to gethostid(), assert_fail(), and errno_location() from some of the C code.  It seems these should be in the NDK libc.a but do not see them there.  I could write dummy stubs (something that returns 0) as fill-ins for these but this seems not to be an optimal path forward.  I would have gone straight to an Android NDK user group but didn't see one offhand.  If someone knows of one that would be great.

thanks,
Steve

Comment: Android has its own libc implementation, and according to [this page](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/docs/status.md) that implementation does not include `gethostid`.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Looks like I'll have to resort to stubs, as I mentioned, as workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to grep NDK package:

```
~/Projects/Android/AS/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147$ grep -irn -e gethostid -e assert_fail -e errno_location --include=*.h
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8/include/sanitizer/netbsd_syscall_hooks.h:744:#define __sanitizer_syscall_pre_compat_43_ogethostid()                         \
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8/include/sanitizer/netbsd_syscall_hooks.h:745:  __sanitizer_syscall_pre_impl_compat_43_ogethostid()
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8/include/sanitizer/netbsd_syscall_hooks.h:746:#define __sanitizer_syscall_post_compat_43_ogethostid(res)                     \
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8/include/sanitizer/netbsd_syscall_hooks.h:747:  __sanitizer_syscall_post_impl_compat_43_ogethostid(res)
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8/include/sanitizer/netbsd_syscall_hooks.h:3250:void __sanitizer_syscall_pre_impl_compat_43_ogethostid(void);
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8/include/sanitizer/netbsd_syscall_hooks.h:3251:void __sanitizer_syscall_post_impl_compat_43_ogethostid(long long res);
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8/include/__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:348:// provide device-side __assert_fail()
toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8/include/__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:349:__device__ static inline void __assert_fail(const char *__message,
toolchains/renderscript/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/clang-include/__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:250:// provide device-side __assert_fail()
toolchains/renderscript/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/clang-include/__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:251:__device__ static inline void __assert_fail(const char *__message,
```

It seems that only `__assert_fail` presents in `__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h` header, but file name tells us that it was not expected for general use.

Comment: Interesting.  Seems to be a binary - always thought header files were text.  Found assert.h in android-ndk-r21d/platforms/android-30/arch-x86_64/usr/include.  There, I see __assert() which I will point my homegrown assert_fail() code to.  On to errno_location() now. Thanks.